# How does JaCoCo for integration tests in Sonar actually work, compared to Cobertura?

Tags: selenium, sonarqube, jacoco

Cobertura works by first 1) instrumenting the source files to be traced, and 2) executing the unit tests and comparing those to the instrumented classes. This way we can calculate the code coverage.

However with JaCoCo for integration tests (Selenium) I have not seen this "instrumentation" phase in documentation. The JaCoCo Agent is just set to dynamically trace the source code covered "on the fly" when executing tests. How does JaCoCo know what source code to compare against, since the code has not been priorly instrumented as with Cobertura? Also, what if I want to exclude some source code?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, by definition Jacoco instruments all java bytecode but you can tune this behavior with help of the 'excludes'/'includes' Jacoco parameters, see http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html.

Comment: Hmm I'm still confused. I understand that Jacoco instruments the classes it touches (i.e. knows about) but this is ofcourse not enough for code coverage, since you ofcourse also want to know what classes are not touched at all. I don't see how Jacoco knows about the "other" classes, through the classloader or what?

Comment: You're right, there are two steps and the second one is automatically taken into account by Sonar.

Comment: Hi Freddy. How does Sonar take the second step automatically into account? I have a few percentage of code coverage for some helper classes used by Selenium tests, but all Web and Business Logic components are 0% for some reason. Why doesn't Sonar include those sources? Those sources are otherwise included in Sonar...